# AngularJS set values of multi-select drop-down using selectize and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selectize.js, multiple-select

With this example ( [JS Bin of pure html select tag](http://jsbin.com/qukexubunu/edit?html,js,output) ) I can able to achieve the pure html select multiple.

But I am using the **selectize plugin**
 https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/  
for dropdown multi-select and i am confused how to populate the already selected values.?

This is what i tried My **HTML**:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">

<select  
multiple 
class="selectSkill"
ng-model="item.storedArray"
ng-options="opt.skillId as opt.skillName for opt in skills"
></select>

</div>
```

My Client:

```
$scope.$selectSkill= $('.selectSkill').selectize({
    valueField: 'skillId',
    labelField: 'skillName',
    searchField: 'skillName',
    maxItems: 5,
    placeholder:"Select Skill",
    options: $scope.skills,
    create: false,
    sortField: {
        field: 'skillName',
        direction: 'asc'
    }
});
$scope.selectizeControlSkills = $scope.$selectSkill[0].selectize;
```

I am loading selectize with class-based(`selectSkill`).

Without populate normal load is working but I'm trying to set values using selectize dynamically.

help is appriciated thank you.

My Demo data:

```
**$scope.skills**
```

[image]

```
**item.storedArray**
```

[image]

Comment: If you're going to use `selectize.js`, you shouldn't mix it with `ng-model` and `ng-options` because the latter won't work. Here's a minimal working example based on your snippets - http://plnkr.co/edit/0JvCrB1QfaRMk3kFBcsf?p=preview

Comment: @miqh thank you it worked. can u post the link as answer i will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the example I created as an answer because it appeared to help the OP.

The advice here is to not mix the use of Selectize with `ng-model` and `ng-options` because they conflict with each other in functionality if applied to the same `select` element.

If you want to use Selectize, it's best to create a wrapper (i.e. a directive, as in my example) that provides the initialisation on `select` elements that need it.

Also, don't forget that since Selectize causes data changes outside the context of AngularJS, you'll need to manually trigger digests (i.e. `scope.$apply()`) to ensure code inside AngularJS sees the latest data.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      { storedArray: ['078...'] },
      { storedArray: [] },
      { storedArray: ['0cc...'] },
    ];
    $scope.skills = [
      { skillId: '078...', skillName: 'Java' },
      { skillId: '0cc...', skillName: 'Cisco UCS' },
    ];
    $scope.itemSelectizeOptions = $scope.items.map(function (item) {
      return {
        valueField: 'skillId',
        labelField: 'skillName',
        options: $scope.skills,
        items: item.storedArray,
        onChange: function (newItems) {
          item.storedArray = newItems;
          // `$apply()` needed because change occurs outside of AngularJS's knowledge
          $scope.$apply();
        }
      };
    })
  })
  .directive('selectize', function () {
    return {
      scope: {
        selectize: '<',
      },
      link: function (scope, el) {
        var selectize = $(el).selectize(scope.selectize);
      },
    };
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="options in itemSelectizeOptions">
    <select
      multiple
      selectize="options"></select>
  </div>
  <pre>{{ items | json }}</pre>
</div>
```